# How do I change the background image position on a website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, background-image

Here's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="temp.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image: url(image.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0px 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <p>This is a test paragraph to fill space</p>
        <input type="button" onClick="size()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the javascript

```
function size() {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
        body.style.backgroundPosition: "0px 30px";
        }
```

but for some reason nothing happens when I click the button. Anyone know what's not working?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
function size() {
        document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "0px 30px";
}
```

Explanation:

Access the `body` using `document.body`

`body.style.backgroundPosition: "0px 30px";` should be `body.style.backgroundPosition = "0px 30px";`

Comment: It’s simpler to use just `document.body` to refer to the `body` element.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code, and partly difficult to track down, but you can get started with debugging by using Developer Tools in your browser. You typically enter them by pressiin the F12 key. The “Console” pane of the tools will show JavaScript errors and other diagnostics.

You will then first see that the colon `:` causes a syntax errors. In JavaScript, you need to use the assignment operator `=`.

Having fixed this, you will see that clicking on the button will cause an error message about `body.style` being undefined. That’s because you have called the `document.getElementsByTagName` function that returns an array of elements, not a single element. The simplest fix to use just `document.body`, which refers to the `body` element.

The remaining bug is more tricky and causes somewhat varying diagnostics in browsers, like “TypeError: size is not a function” in Firefox. The reason is that the invocation `size()` is inside an event handler in the `<input>` tag, and there the implied context is the `<input>` element node. And that node has the `size` property, which reflects to the HTML markup attribute `size`. This property is defined even though the markup does not have an explicit attribute; it is then defaulted to a browser-dependent value, typically 20. Anyway, in this context the identifier `size` denotes that property, which has a numeric value, not a function.

There are two simple ways to fix this bug. You can change the invocation `size()` to `window.size()`, thereby referring to the globally defined identifier `size` (it is global, i.e. a property of the `window` object, since you define a function with that name at the topmost level). Alternatively, you can change the function name to something else, just avoiding anything that could be a property of the `<input>` element node. You could use `Size` for example, or `changeBackgroundPosition`. So in HTML you could have

```
<input type="button" value="Change" onClick="changeBackgroundPosition()">
```

and in JavaScript

```
function changeBackgroundPosition() {
  document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "0 30px";
}
```